# How to implement a survey in iOS

Tags: ios, textview, survey

i would like to implement a simple survey within my app like in the following screenshot:

[Survey app sample screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/250747280g1F)

There is a label with a title, a text view with the question to be asked and a segmented control to give the vote. I want the user read the question, give his vote so the next button (on the top right) will be enabled, and so he could go to the next screen with the next question.

The problem is that i didnt figure out clearly how to implement this.
Should I use a scroll view with a page control? or separated view controllers? or something else?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a scrollView.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320*pageCount, 480)];

for(int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++){

//Create your labels and segmented control here

}

}

-(void)nextButtonPressed{
int currentPage = (scrollView.contentOffset.x/320);
int nextPage = currentPage + 1;

 [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320*nextPage, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];

}
```

The concept is creating a scrollView that will contain all your pages. You will have a int which I called pageCount. So each time you enable next button and it is pressed by the user, the scrollView will scroll to the next page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i have one more question: so inside the for loop i should create all my labels and add them in different coordinates position?

Comment: You can do this:  `label.frame = CGRectMake(320*i,0,320,480);` Use the i for creating the labels and segmented control.